# Python regex for nested XML elements

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a text (not a properly formed XML document) with some words in XML tags like this:

```
We have Potter the <term attrib="LINE:246">wizard</term> interacting with<term attrib="LINE:36080">witches</term> and <term attrib="LINE:360">goblins</term>  talking about <term attrib="LINE:337"><term attrib="LINE:329"><term attrib="LINE:468">dark</term></term> <term attrib="LINE:375">arts</term></term> in regions to the east of Hogwarts.
```

I need to extract the terms in the XML tags.
My problem is that I do not know what regex I should use to get a nested element like this:

```
<term><term>something</term><term>else</term></term>
```

I am using python, for my work, and I have tried the following for my work:

```
re.findall(r'(<term.+?</term>)', textfile)
```

But I get something like this:

```
<term><term>something</term>
```

This is bad, because I am missing the rest.
I also tried the following  greedy version(which is worse):

```
re.findall(r'(<term.+</term>)' , textfile)
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113364/regex-for-nested-xml-attributes informative on the problems associated with attempting to parse nested XML with regex ...

Comment: ObZalgo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4014959 :)

Comment: Only PyPi regex module offers a recursive regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. Regex languages can't (normally) count, so using it for stuff like this will be extremely fragile. Use a proper xml parser with a nice front-end, like BeautifulSoup. It will save you time and getter better results that are less hackish than a regex ever will be.

See the [great docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) for examples

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
text = 'We have Potter the <term attrib="LINE:246">wizard</term> interacting with<term attrib="LINE:36080">witches</term> and <term attrib="LINE:360">goblins</term>  talking about <term attrib="LINE:337"><term attrib="LINE:329"><term attrib="LINE:468">dark</term></term> <term attrib="LINE:375">arts</term></term> in regions to the east of Hogwarts.'
text = re.sub("<.+?>", '', text)
text = re.sub("  ", " ", text)
print(text)
```

This should cut out every `<tag>` and `</tag>` there is, leaving everything else intact.

Of course, it will be messy if there are any `<` signs that aren't part of an XML tag.